# how to change the style of only one react component that is being render through .map() when the component is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

how to change the style of only one react component that is being render through .map() when the component is clicked. I'm trying to make a quiz and I want the component background to change to one color if the right answer is clicked and to another if the wrong answer is clicked. Using only functional components and hooks

```
const [correct, setCorrect] = useState(false);

const styles = {
    correct: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
    incorrect: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
};

const DUMMY_QUESTIONS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        question: 'What is the Big O of merge sort?',
        options: [
            { number: 1, answer: 'O(1)'},
            { number: 2, answer: 'O(log n)' },
            { number: 3, answer: 'O(n)' },
            { number: 4, answer: 'O(n log n)' }
        ],
        answer: 'O(n log n)'
    }
];

const handler = opt => {
    if (opt === DUMMY_QUESTIONS[0].answer){
        console.log(opt);
    }
}

return (
    <Fragment>
        <div>
            <Question question={DUMMY_QUESTIONS[0].question} />
        </div>
        <div>
            {DUMMY_QUESTIONS[0].options.map(option =>
                <AnswerOption 
                    key={option.number} 
                    id={option.number}
                    option={option.answer}
                    click={() => {if (option.answer === DUMMY_QUESTIONS[0].answer) setCorrect(true) }}
                    correct={correct} />
            )}
        </div>
    </Fragment>
);
```

other Component:

```
const AnswerOption = props => {
return (
    <div 
        className={`answer-option ${props.correct && 'answer-option--correct'}`} onClick={() => {props.click(props.option)}} >
        <p>{props.option}</p>
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: tell us which is the actual behaviour, please

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make it work, use the state for `selectedAnswer` then use selectedAnswer for comparing items inside the style.

Also, I did make you another state for the user answers for saving answers on that.

```js
const styles = {
  correct: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
  incorrect: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
};
const DUMMY_QUESTIONS = [
  {
      id: 1,
      question: 'What is the Big O of merge sort?',
      options: [
        { number: 1, answer: 'O(1)' },
        { number: 2, answer: 'O(log n)' },
        { number: 3, answer: 'O(n)' },
        { number: 4, answer: 'O(n log n)' }
      ],
      answer: 'O(log n)'
  },{
      id: 2,
      question: 'Another question?',
      options: [
        { number: 1, answer: 'O(1)' },
        { number: 2, answer: 'O(log n)' },
        { number: 3, answer: 'O(n)' },
        { number: 4, answer: 'O(n log n)' }
      ],
      answer: 'O(n)'
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [userAnswers, setUserAnswers] = React.useState({});

  return(
   <React.Fragment>
      {DUMMY_QUESTIONS.map(question => (
        <Question question={question} userAnswers={userAnswers} setUserAnswers={setUserAnswers}/>
      ))}
      <hr/>
      <p>Object of user answers : {JSON.stringify(userAnswers)}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const Question = ({question, userAnswers, setUserAnswers}) => {
  const [slectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = React.useState(null);

  const clickHandler = (selected) => {
    setUserAnswers({...userAnswers,[question.id]:{
      selectedAnswer: selected,
      isCorrect: selected === question.answer
    }})
    setSelectedAnswer(selected);
  }

  const styleChecker = (option) => 
    slectedAnswer ?
    slectedAnswer === option ? 
    question.answer === slectedAnswer ? 
    styles.correct : styles.incorrect : {} : {};
    
  return (
     <div>
        <h4>{question.question}</h4>
        {question.options.map(option => (
          <AnswerOption
            key={option.number}
            id={option.number}
            option={option.answer}
            onClick={() => slectedAnswer ? {} : clickHandler(option.answer)}
            style={styleChecker(option.answer)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
};

const AnswerOption = ({ option, ...rest }) => (
  <div {...rest}>
    <p>{option}</p>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: doing it this way, how would you make the ones you already clicked to stay either green or red?

Comment: Already done that, what do you mean `stay either green or red`? did you check snippets?